# How do I fetch orgusers beyond the 1st 100 using the Google Apps OrgUser provisioning API feed

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I am using Zend's gdata library for the Google Apps provisioning API. Since Zend doesn't yet support fetching org users (no retrieve function provided by the library for this feed), I am making a custom gdata query to the url (as suggested in the documentation developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_organization_users_experimental):

```
apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/'.$customerId.'?get=all
```

This works well for <= 100 users.

Now, I have created a domain with 125 users across 5 OUs. When I fetch the above URI, I get the 1st 100 users (as documented and expected). However, I could not find the pagination link mentioned here: developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/reference#Results_Pagination

Here's the start of my orguser feed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'><id>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxxxx</id><updated>2013-01-06T08:17:43.520Z</updated><**link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxxxx?get=all&amp;startKey=RASS03jtnz0s2orxmbn.**'/><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxx'/>
```

I tried the `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxxxx?get=all&amp;startKey=RASS03jtnz0s2orxmbn`. link but it gives me the exact same 100 users that the `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxxxx?get=all` link gives. This is the only occurrence of the word "next" in my feed and so there is not other URI I can try to fetch the next 25 users.

So I have only been able to get 100 users from this API call. How do I go about fetching the next 25 users? Examples/code would be really appreciated. Or what am I doing wrong?

Please help - this is blocking an urgent delivery.

Thanks!,
Vinay.

Comment: The OrgUser API is _Experimental_, and is very unstable.... I recommend against its use for any serious thing   

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#managing_organization_users

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd request should look like:

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/C00xxxxxx?startKey=RASS03jtnz0s2orxmbn&get=all
```

startKey should be set to the value of the next parameter and get should continue to be all for each page request.

Also, make sure the URL is decoded, if & is encoded as `&amp;` in the request, then Google's servers will see all of `all&amp;startKey=RASS03jtnz0s2orxmbn` as the value of get and it won't see a startKey parameter at all.